# Why is there a baloo_filemetadat process even though I have disabled baloo?

Tags: kde, baloo

Why is there a baloo_filemetad process, even though I have disabled baloo?

```
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~$ balooctl status
Baloo is currently disabled. To enable, please run balooctl enable
bruni@bruni-Inspiron-5547:~$ ps -A | grep baloo
12863 ?        00:00:00 baloo_filemetad
```

I am not interested in this purely academically, but this process is often the culprit when something is hanging in my system (I use a lot of mounted filesystems (mainly webdav and samba). I really love KDE since 4.3, but they always seemed to have a thing for file indexing and nonetheless never managed to get it right.

I am on Kubuntu 18.10, KDE Plasma Version 5.13.5.

Comment: What version of Kubuntu are you on? I'm currently on KDE neon 5.14 and have baloo enabled (running). Your `ps -A` command shows just `baloo_file` and `baloorunner`. But mine is a standalone system without anything else mounted; no samba. Maybe you could ask at https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/ and at https://www.kubuntuforums.net/forum.php as well?

Comment: @DKBose Thank you for the reply. "Your ps -A command shows just baloo_file and baloorunner". I do not understand that statement. I only see one process.

Comment: What I wrote was for my system using your command with baloo enabled. Those are the only two processes. No `baloo_filemetad`. That maybe because I don't have any mounted devices? But I googled for `baloo_filemetad` and came up empty. Which I why I suggested asking elsewhere in case people with more experience can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor ?**

If the 'baloo_filemetad' is a truncated version of the 'baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor':

By Rémi Verschelde in https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=332065#c32 :

> ..for metadata extraction to work on non-indexed files in Plasma 5,
>   make sure that you have baloo-widgets installed on your distro (or the
>   package containing /usr/bin/baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor if named
>   differently). This tool is the one used for on-the-fly extraction of
>   metadata when Baloo's file indexing is off.

```
$ baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor
Usage: baloo_filemetadata_temp_extractor url

Arguments:
  url
```

---Edit---

It seems that the 'ps -A' will truncate the output

With the:

```
$ watch -n 1 'ps -A | grep baloo'
```

[image]

With the KDE System Activity:

[image]